# Download Azure VM to local Hyper-V

Tags: azure, hyper-v

I am looking for a way to migrate my VM's off Azure so I can run them locally on my Win8, Hyper-V enabled machine.  Is this possible?   If so can someone point me to a tutorial or some reference for doing so?  My research has not found a straight forward approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

https://web.archive.org/web/20161205162932/https://www.opsgility.com/blog/windows-azure-powershell-reference-guide/uploading-and-downloading-vhds-to-windows-azure/

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-us/ea159bb9-fd67-4248-b6f4-1b3904a63455/how-to-download-a-vhd-from-windows-azure-to-my-local-pc-?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows

Just one information: you'll pay for each MB that you'll download.

Comment: Do you know the price per MB for downloading?

Comment: @ChiliYago unfortunately no, you could simulate with azure calculator in the past, but this new one it's not possible. At least, I didn't find. Take a look http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=virtual-machines